# How to connect a database which is on a VMware virtual machine with ASP ?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection, virtual-machine

I want to connect a sql database which is on a Vmware virtual machine.
And I have a class which includes this code rows :

```
 public SqlConnection baglan()
{
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.13.128; Initial Catalog=DbFilm; Integrated Security=true;");
    baglanti.Open();
    return (baglanti);
}
```

and I cannot connect to this database i think i need to tell the machine the password and username too right ?

Comment: Is the VM on the same domain as your physical computer?

Comment: Make sure your VM is confgured correctly. e.g. Port is free, you have access to it and so on.
It's probably an network issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ***Integrated Security=true*** in your connection string, so application is using your windows login to authenticate to database.

You have to configure the database to accept such authentication or use some sql server login and password in connection string.

Here you have a link describing all options in connection string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx